# How do I track a conversion which captures users from Mailchimp that complete a form on a separate page?

Tags: google-tag-manager, analytics, mailchimp, google-analytics-4

GTM task for Google Analytics 4

I have Mailchimp email campaigns which include links to pages advertising our events. The links from the email include a UTM query string like so: `https://www.example.com/events/event-name?mc_cid=31a4d2cc0a&mc_eid=f948d3f0c2`

From there, users need to click a button that loads a new page `https://www.example.com/events/event-name/register` with the registration form.

I know how to set up a conversion for users that click the **REGISTER** button at the end of the form, but I specifically want to track the submission clicks from users whose source is the Mailchimp email. I am struggling to do this though, as the Referrer field is blank on this website, and I am not sure how else I can neatly track the origin of that user session.

Currently, I have set up a tag which triggers when a **Page URL** contains `?mc_cid=` and click URL contains `/register`. I don't know if this is the right path, but I was wondering if there was a way to pair this with a trigger when the **REGISTER** button is clicked on the following page.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like UTMs that apply to MailChimps platform and not GA4.

If you append GA4 specific UTMs then you shouldn't need do to anything more. I would suggest using `utm_campaign`, `utm_source`, and `utm_medium`.

With these UTM parameters, you will be able to segment the event by each of those and see how many people are coming from your campaign.

You can read more about it in [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10917952?hl=en#parameters&zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

Comment: To my understanding, this will allow me to track users entering the first page from my campaign. However, there are 2 separate pages involved here:  
1. the landing page `https://www.example.com/events/event-name?mc_cid=31a4d2cc0a&mc_eid=f948d3f0c2`
2. the registration form `https://www.example.com/events/event-name/register`

It is on the second page I want to capture users that both complete the form by clicking the `REGISTER` button *and* came from page 1 (unable to use referrers on my website).

Correct me if I am wrong, but your solution only tracks the entries to the landing page?

Comment: For UTM campaign codes, from my experience they track the user throughout their session after they have landed on the site. Not just the first page. So even though they came and hit that first page and the next clicks don't have the UTM, you should still be able to see the events from that person's session.

Comment: Interesting. Would you be able to show me steps on how to set an appropriate tag to track that - assuming I set up an appropriate UTM?